# Como puedo obtener solo el campo de una tabla de vuetify para enviar post en axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify

Como puedo obtener solo el campo de una tabla de vuetify para enviar post por en axios, tengo una tabla como lo muestro en el siguiente código

```
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              append-icon="mdi-magnify"
              label="Search"
              single-line
              hide-details
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="students"
            :search="search"
          >
            <template  v-slot:item.estado="{ item }">
              <v-btn v-if="item.estado">Agregar</v-btn>
              
              <v-btn v-else disabled>Temporalmente sin acceso</v-btn>   
            </template>
            
          </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

y de script tengo lo del siguiente codigo

```
   const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   //template: "#muestragraphql",
   vuetify: new Vuetify(),    
   data() {
         return {
           search: '',
           headers: [
             { text: 'num_list', align: 'start', value: 'id'},
             { text: 'Nombre', align: 'start', value: 'nombre'},
             { text: 'Opciones', value: 'estado' }
           ],
           students: [
        {
          id: 1,
          nombre: pedro,
          estado: activo,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          nombre: juan,
          estado: activo,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          nombre: jose,
          estado: activo,
        },
       ]
         };
 });
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se le de click solo envié el id por post con axios, y como ven necesito que primero se verifique que el estado del alumno es activo. A continuación igualmente agrego una imagen de la tabla generada para mayor referencia.

[image: tabla]

Comment: Y ese boton, que metodo ejecuta? no le podes pasar por parametro el id?

Comment: quiero saber como obtener el parámetro para hacer un método @gbianchi

Comment: no esta en item.id?

Comment: `add (item) {
        axios.post('http://localhost/list?id=' + item.id)
          .then(response => {
            this.response = response
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
      },`  hice ese método pero en la consola me sale que item.id esta **undefined** @gbianchi

Comment: donde y como lo estas llamando? como le estas pasando el parametro item?

Comment: Lo llamo al darle click al botón agregar y paso el parámetro desde la tabla @gbianchi

Comment: Yo no veo eso que decis por ningun lado en tu codigo....